# How to fill Form::select more beautiful?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the following form:

```
 <?=Form::select('stars', array(
                            1 => 1,
                            2 => 2,
                            3 => 3,
                            4 => 4,
                            5 => 5
                        ), null, ["placeholder" => "Stars", "class" => "w-select"]);?>
```

It looks awful. How can I reformate array in `Form::select` that keys will be from 1 to 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use select range instead of select.

`{!! Form::selectRange('stars', 1, 5, null, ["placeholder" => "Stars", "class" => "w-select"]) !!}`

more details:https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#drop-down-lists